# In Firefox 4, how to move links addresses indication from address bar back to status bar?

Tags: firefox

When I move mouse pointer over a link on a page, the link source address was traditionally displayed in browser's status bar (below the main window area).

Firefox 4 shows this information right in the address bar, alongside with the current page address. Of course these two never fit in the address bar together (even alone they don't always do today).

Can I set up Firefox 4 to display a pointed link source address the classic way - in its status bar ("Add-on bar", as it is called in Firefox 4) instead of address bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is reported to work-you are not alone. it will not display by deflaut but an easy customizing explained in 'more about this add-on' fixes that.
Status-4-Evar:: Add-ons for Firefox.  hope all works out ok.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/235283/

Comment: Theoretically the answer is correct, but actually this does not work. The extension stopped link information to appear in the location bar and moved some icons from the right to the left in the status bar, but links source addresses still don't appear in the status bar :-(

Comment: I've submitted the extension bug report.